# XML string to XML document

Tags: c#, xml

I have a whole XML document in a **String** which i need to convert to a XML document and parse tags in the document

Comment: @svick so why stack-overflow flow created for ?

Comment: @svick it is totally ok to ask such simple questions here. Look at my question about AND and OR in if statements. No one ever complained it was too simple to ask at Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

This code sample is taken from [csharp-examples.net](http://www.csharp-examples.net/xml-nodes-by-name/), written by [Jan Slama](http://www.csharp-examples.net/jan-slama/):

> To find nodes in an XML file you can use XPath expressions. Method XmlNode.Selec­tNodes returns a list of nodes selected by the XPath string. Method XmlNode.Selec­tSingleNode finds the first node that matches the XPath string.

XML:

> ```
> <Names>
>     <Name>
>         <FirstName>John</FirstName>
>         <LastName>Smith</LastName>
>     </Name>
>     <Name>
>         <FirstName>James</FirstName>
>         <LastName>White</LastName>
>     </Name>
> </Names>
> ```

CODE:

> ```
> XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
> xml.LoadXml(myXmlString); // suppose that myXmlString contains "<Names>...</Names>"
>
> XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Names/Name");
> foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
> {
>   string firstName = xn["FirstName"].InnerText;
>   string lastName = xn["LastName"].InnerText;
>   Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
> }
> ```

Comment: Often I find the path syntax to not work. However, you can also access a node by for example: `xml["Names"]`. If you want to access `result/statusCode`for example, you could access it by using `xmlNode["result"]["statusCode"].InnerText` (this will give you the value of the first instance of `result/statusCode`).

Comment: This excellent example is copied from http://www.csharp-examples.net/xml-nodes-by-name/

Comment: GREAT! Copied but first in this platform.

Comment: can you please look into one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55440649/unable-to-get-values-from-soap-response-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 19):

Using [Linq to xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb387098.aspx)

Add a reference to System.Xml.Linq

and use

```
XDocument.Parse(string xmlString)
```

Edit: [Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387053.aspx) follows, xml data (TestConfig.xml)..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Tests>
  <Test TestId="0001" TestType="CMD">
    <Name>Convert number to string</Name>
    <CommandLine>Examp1.EXE</CommandLine>
    <Input>1</Input>
    <Output>One</Output>
  </Test>
  <Test TestId="0002" TestType="CMD">
    <Name>Find succeeding characters</Name>
    <CommandLine>Examp2.EXE</CommandLine>
    <Input>abc</Input>
    <Output>def</Output>
  </Test>
  <Test TestId="0003" TestType="GUI">
    <Name>Convert multiple numbers to strings</Name>
    <CommandLine>Examp2.EXE /Verbose</CommandLine>
    <Input>123</Input>
    <Output>One Two Three</Output>
  </Test>
  <Test TestId="0004" TestType="GUI">
    <Name>Find correlated key</Name>
    <CommandLine>Examp3.EXE</CommandLine>
    <Input>a1</Input>
    <Output>b1</Output>
  </Test>
  <Test TestId="0005" TestType="GUI">
    <Name>Count characters</Name>
    <CommandLine>FinalExamp.EXE</CommandLine>
    <Input>This is a test</Input>
    <Output>14</Output>
  </Test>
  <Test TestId="0006" TestType="GUI">
    <Name>Another Test</Name>
    <CommandLine>Examp2.EXE</CommandLine>
    <Input>Test Input</Input>
    <Output>10</Output>
  </Test>
</Tests>
```

C# usage...

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("TestConfig.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> tests =
    from el in root.Elements("Test")
    where (string)el.Element("CommandLine") == "Examp2.EXE"
    select el;
foreach (XElement el in tests)
    Console.WriteLine((string)el.Attribute("TestId"));
```

This code produces the following output:
0002
0006

Answer (score 6):

Depending on what document type you want you can use [`XmlDocument.LoadXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) or [`XDocument.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538303.aspx).

Answer (score -4):

Try this code:

```
var myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
myXmlDocument.LoadXml(theString);
```

Comment: down vote -> The signature of the method Load is: void Load(string filename)

Comment: The method is LoadXml, then myXmlDocument.LoadXml(theString);