# how to represent \r or \n or \t in XML and read them back correctly using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml

For example:

```
<codes>\n\r\t</codes>
```

When I read the node "codes" in a string, it should contain the 3 characters `'\n'`, `'\r'`, `'\t'` as if it was `s="\n\r\t";`

Comment: TIP: You can use the "Code Sample" formatting tool (in the toolbar) and backticks (same key as ~tilde~) to format that section like I did here. :-)

Comment: can you show actual code .. also are you wanting to maintain the whitespaces in the XML file..? for example `xDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
xDoc.Save(...);` please clarify your question as well as show example of XML that you want your end result to look like..

Comment: I can't tell from the current question but this is a possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402596/xml-string-to-xml-document

Comment: even though it's possible to do this (as stated in the answer(s)), I would seriously consider dealing with this in-code. There's really no need whatsoever to include formatting in XML.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use hexadecimal character entities:

```
<codes>&#xA;&#xD;&#x9;</codes>
```

Comment: Note that answer is missing mentioning of "preserve whitespace" mode of reading XML and line break normalization... Otherwise ok.